# Integrating Google maps into ionic

Tags: angularjs, cordova, google-maps, ionic-framework, visual-studio-2015

I'm working in Visual Studio '15, trying to get a cordova tab template project running. I'm simply trying to load up google maps on my tab-map.html, but i'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: $scope.init is not a function
at new <anonymous> (http://localhost:4400/js/controllers.js:22:12)
at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:4400/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:18010:14)
at $controller (http://localhost:4400/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:23412:28)
at self.appendViewElement (http://localhost:4400/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:59900:24)
at Object.render (http://localhost:4400/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:57893:41)
at Object.init (http://localhost:4400/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:57813:20)
at self.render (http://localhost:4400/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:59759:14)
at self.register (http://localhost:4400/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:59717:10)
at updateView (http://localhost:4400/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:65398:23)
at http://localhost:4400/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:65375:11
```

here is my tab-map.html:

```
<ion-view view-title="Map">

  <ion-content class="padding">
    <ion-refresher (ionRefresh)="doRefresh($event)">
        <ion-refresher-content
            pullingIcon="arrow-dropdown"
            pullingText="Pull to refresh"
            refreshingSpinner="circles"
            refreshingText="Refreshing...">
        </ion-refresher-content>
    </ion-refresher>

    <h2 align="center">Map</h2>
    <div id="map" data-tap-disabled="true"></div>
  </ion-content>

  <ion-footer-bar class="bar-dark">
    <a ng-click="centerOnMe()" class="button button-icon icon ion-navigate">Find Me</a>
  </ion-footer-bar>

</ion-view>
```

and my controller.js, this controller is in the middle of the js file, so there is no semicolon at the end of it

```
.controller('MapCtrl', function ($scope, $ionicLoading, $compile) {

$scope.init() = function () {
    console.log("Is this thing on?");
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(35.182217, -83.381418);

    var mapOptions = {
        center: myLatlng,
        zoom: 16,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
        mapOptions);

    //Marker + infowindow + angularjs compiled ng-click
    var contentString = "<div><a ng-click='clickTest()'>Click me!</a></div>";
    var compiled = $compile(contentString)($scope);

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: compiled[0]
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title: 'Franklin, NC'
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });

    $scope.map = map;
}
//google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

$scope.centerOnMe = function () {
    if (!$scope.map) {
        return;
    }

    $scope.loading = $ionicLoading.show({
        content: 'Getting current location...',
        showBackdrop: false
    });

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (pos) {
        $scope.map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude,
            pos.coords.longitude));
        $scope.loading.hide();
    }, function(error) {
        alert('Unable to get location: ' + error.message);
    });
};

$scope.clickTest = function() {
    alert('Example of infowindow with ng-click')
};

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Write your init function as below

```
$scope.init = function () {}
```

instead of

```
$scope.init() = function () {}
```

Comment: thanks for the response, but i am still getting the same error! :(

Answer (score 0):

so i was able to get the map to display on emulation via VS 2015. in tab-map.html I added ng-init="init()"

```
<ion-content class="padding" ng-init="init()">

    <h2 align="center">Map</h2>
    <div id="map" data-tap-disabled="true"></div>
</ion-content>
```

Now I get this error when trying to run on mobile:

```
"ReferenceError: google is not defined
at Scope.$scope.init (file:///android_asset/www/js/controllers.js:24:28)
at fn (eval at compile (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:27638:15), <anonymous>:4:203)
at Scope.$eval (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:30395:28)
at pre (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:39095:15)
at invokeLinkFn (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:22993:9)
at nodeLinkFn (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:22371:11)
at compositeLinkFn (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:21703:13)
at nodeLinkFn (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:22387:24)
at compositeLinkFn (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:21703:13)
at publicLinkFn (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:21583:30)"
```

which refers to the following line:

```
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(35.182217, -83.381418);
```